# writing help texts with Django

Tags: python, html, database, django, templates

How do i put help texts in a template so that with ease the user can input data in the right format?
Say for example, a DateTimeField...how do I placed the format of the field e.g. (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) without affecting the space for the default errorlist?

Answer (score 1):

You could [specify the help_text of the form field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#help-text), or [specify the help_text of the model field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#help-text). It should not affect error handling at all.